# Matrix from Python to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, file-io, import, matrix

I'm working with Python and MATLAB right now and I have a 2D array in Python that I need to write to a file and then be able to read it into MATLAB as a matrix. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

If you use numpy/scipy, you can use the `scipy.io.savemat` function:

```
import numpy, scipy.io

arr = numpy.arange(9) # 1d array of 9 numbers
arr = arr.reshape((3, 3))  # 2d array of 3x3

scipy.io.savemat('c:/tmp/arrdata.mat', mdict={'arr': arr})
```

Now, you can load this data into MATLAB using File -> Load Data.  Select the file and the `arr` variable (a 3x3 matrix) will be available in your environment.

Note: I did this on scipy 0.7.0.  (scipy 0.6 has `savemat` in the `scipy.io.mio` module.)  See the [latest documentation for more detail](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html)

EDIT: updated link thanks to [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095265/matrix-from-python-to-matlab#comment909707_1095324).

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps this one would work better: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html

Comment: The link works fine at my end.  But your link is better -- it's for the latest docs (0.7+) whereas mine was for 0.6, hence the different module (I have an old bookmark).  Thanks gnovice!

Answer (score 9):

I think [ars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095265/matrix-from-python-to-matlab/1095324#1095324) has the most straight-forward answer for saving the data to a .mat file from Python (using [savemat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html)). To add just a little to their answer, you can also load the .mat file into MATLAB programmatically using the [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/load.shtml) function instead of doing it by hand using the MATLAB command window menu...

You can use either the *command syntax* form of LOAD:

```
load c:/tmp/arrdata.mat
```

or the *function syntax* form (if you have the file path stored in a string):

```
filePath = 'c:/tmp/arrdata.mat';
data = load(filePath);
```

Comment: +1; Neat!  I don't use matlab enough, and always end up fumbling in the menus instead of just looking for the right command.  Load would seem obvious.  Ahem.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small function to do this same thing, without need for numpy. It takes a list of lists and returns a string with a MATLAB-formatted matrix.

```
def arrayOfArrayToMatlabString(array):
    return '[' + "\n ".join(" ".join("%6g" % val for val in line) for line in array) + ']'
```

Write `"myMatrix = " + arrayOfArrayToMatlabString(array)` to a `.m` file,  open it in matlab, and execute it.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably use `numpy.savetxt('yourfile.mat',yourarray)` in Python
and then `yourarray = load('yourfile.mat')` in MATLAB.

Comment: In MATLAB 2016b, this only works if you use `yourarray = load('yourfile.mat', '-ASCII')`.

Answer (score 4):

You could write the matrix in Python to a CSV file and read it in MATLAB using csvread.

Comment: I tried including a link to csvread (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html&http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS294US304&q=matlab+csvread&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also [call matlab](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) directly from python:

```
from mlabwrap import mlab
import numpy 
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
mlab.plot(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

The toolbox *npy-matlab* can read `*.npy` binary files into MATLAB. `*.npy` files can be directly exported with the NumPy module. From the documentation:

```
>> a = rand(5,4,3);
>> writeNPY(a, 'a.npy');
>> b = readNPY('a.npy');
>> sum(a(:)==b(:))
ans =

    60
```

*npy-matlab* is a simple collection of M-files [available from GitHub](https://github.com/kwikteam/npy-matlab), with a 2-clause BSD licence.