# Python to MATLAB: exporting list of strings using scipy.io

Tags: python, string, matlab, scipy, mat-file

I am trying to export a list of text strings from Python to MATLAB using scipy.io. I would like to use scipy.io because my desired .mat file should include both numerical matrices (which I learned to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095265/matrix-from-python-to-matlab)) and text cell arrays.

I tried:

```
import scipy.io
my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
scipy.io.savemat('test.mat', mdict={'my_list': my_list})
```

In MATLAB, I load test.mat and get a character array:

```
my_list =

adg
beh
cfi
```

How do I make scipy.io export a list into a MATLAB cell array?

Comment: You might also be interested in my python-in-MATLAB project: http://github.com/kw/pymex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make my_list an array of numpy objects:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
my_list = np.zeros((3,), dtype=np.object)
my_list[:] = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
scipy.io.savemat('test.mat', mdict={'my_list': my_list})
```

Then it will be saved in a cell format. There might be a better way of putting it into a np.object, but I took this way from the [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html).

Comment: For posterity: an easier way to make an object array is `np.asarray(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='object')`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the contents of the list are exported properly, they are just transposed and placed in a character array. You can easily convert it to the desired cell array of strings in MATLAB by transposing it and using [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html), which places each row in a separate cell:

```
>> my_list = ['adg';'beh';'cfi'];  %# Your example
>> my_list = cellstr(my_list')    %'# A 3-by-1 cell array of strings

my_list = 

    'abc'
    'def'
    'ghi'
```

Granted, this doesn't address the more *general* issue of exporting data as a cell array from Python to MATLAB, but it should help with the *specific* problem you list above.