# Writing and reading .mat using scipy.io changes dictionary contents

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I am trying to write a dictionary to a .mat file using scipy.io.savemat(),
but when I do, the contents change!

Here is the array I wish to assign to the dictionary key "Genes":

```
vectorizeddf.index.values.astype(np.str_)
```

Which prints as

```
array(['44M2.3', 'A0A087WSV2', 'A0A087WT57', ..., 'tert-rmrp_human',
       'tert-terc_human', 'wisp3 varinat'], 
      dtype='<U44')
```

Then I do

```
genedict = {"Genes": vectorizeddf.index.values.astype(np.str_), 
         "X": vectorizeddf.values, 
         "ID": vectorizeddf.columns.values.astype(np.str_)}
import scipy.io as sio
sio.savemat("goa_human.mat", genedict)
```

But when I load the dictionary using

```
goadict = sio.loadmat("goa_human.mat")
```

My strings get padded with spaces!

```
>>> goadict['Genes']
array(['44M2.3                                      ',
   'A0A087WSV2                                  ',
   'A0A087WT57                                  ', ...,
   'tert-rmrp_human                             ',
   'tert-terc_human                             ',
   'wisp3 varinat                               '], 
  dtype='<U44')
```

Which is far from ideal.
On the other hand, when I access

```
genedict['ID']
```

I get

```
array(['GO:0000002', 'GO:0000003', 'GO:0000009', ..., 'GO:2001303',
       'GO:2001306', 'GO:2001311'], 
     dtype='<U10')
```

Which is the original format of the array before saving. It seems to me that the issue is in the dtype, but I did my best to cast both of them as strings. I am not sure why one is `<U44` and the other is `<U10`. How might I resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you showing us `genedict['ID']`?  Show us `genedict['Genes']`.  Compare the same key.  Different keys will have different `dtypes`.

Comment: @hpaulj implicitly he did, with the first three blocks of code

Comment: The issue is that in order to save cell arrays of strings, the array should be constructed with `np.asarray(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='object')`.

Comment: I don't think he's worried about the data structure in MATLAB (cell, structure, etc).  He's just writing and reading in Python.  As far as I can tell the 'Genes' value is saved as 'U44' and loaded as the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706697/saving-numpy-structure-array-to-mat-file - yesterday's `savemat` question.

Comment: @hpaulj except he's writing a `mat` file, which imposes MATLAB's constraints, where char arrays are space padded. The correct way to save strings in `mat` is with cell arrays.

Comment: Yes, I just went through a reinvented the answers in your link.

Comment: My bad! goadict['ID'] printed the same as genedict['ID']. I just pasted the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to save a variety of objects:

```
In [597]: d={'alist':['one','two','three','four'],
   .....: 'adict':{'one':np.arange(5)},
   .....: 'strs': np.array(['one','two','three','four']),
   .....: 'objs': np.array(['one','two','three','four'],dtype=object)}

In [598]: d
Out[598]: 
{'alist': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
 'adict': {'one': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])},
 'objs': array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], dtype=object),
 'strs': array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], 
       dtype='<U5')}
In [599]: io.savemat('test.mat',d)

In [600]: dd=io.loadmat('test.mat')
In [601]: dd
Out[601]: 
{'adict': array([[([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],)]], 
       dtype=[('one', 'O')]),
 'strs': array(['one  ', 'two  ', 'three', 'four '], 
       dtype='<U5'),
 'alist': array(['one  ', 'two  ', 'three', 'four '], 
       dtype='<U5'),
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0....',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'objs': array([[array(['one'], 
       dtype='<U3'),
         array(['two'], 
       dtype='<U3'),
         array(['three'], 
       dtype='<U5'),
         array(['four'], 
       dtype='<U4')]], dtype=object),
 '__globals__': []}
```

This is for scipy version, '0.14.1'; not a particularly new one, but I haven't read of recent changes in this `io` code.

And in Octave I get:

```
octave:14> data = load('test.mat')
data =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    alist =

one  
two  
three
four 

    adict =

      scalar structure containing the fields:

        one =

          0  1  2  3  4


    objs = 
    {
      [1,1] = one
      [1,2] = two
      [1,3] = three
      [1,4] = four
    }
    strs =

one  
two  
three
four
```

The `list` and `str` array both produce `(4,5)` character arrays in Octave, while the `dtype=object` array produces the cell array of strings.

In both `d` and `dd`, the `strs` array is `U5` and takes up 80 bytes (4 words*5 char/word *4 bytes/char), but in `dd`, the strings have been padded with blanks.

```
In [617]: d['strs'][0]
Out[617]: 'one'
In [618]: dd['strs'][0]
Out[618]: 'one  '
In [619]: d['strs'][0].tostring()
Out[619]: b'o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00'
In [620]: dd['strs'][0].tostring()
Out[620]: b'o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00'
```

I haven't paid attention as to why arrays like `d['strs']` don't display the strings with padding. Some how it's distinguishing between blanks and 'empty' bytes.  Note this is with Py3, where the default string is unicode.  I don't know if the Py2 byte strings are different (except they do take up 1 byte/char).

So yes, `io.savemat` does change the string array (and lists) by adding blanks to the full `dtype` width.  The purpose is to create a MATLAB style character matrix.

@zeeMonkeez's link covers this, including a way of converting the character matrix to cell:

```
octave:25> cellstr(data.strs)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = one
  [2,1] = two
  [3,1] = three
  [4,1] = four
```

[Python to MATLAB: exporting list of strings using scipy.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433924/python-to-matlab-exporting-list-of-strings-using-scipy-io)