# How to pass variables between Matlab and python using matlab.engine

Tags: python, matlab

I have a python code within which I want to manipulate a list using a Matlab function and return it as a new list to python.

To test `matlab.engine`, I've tried the following:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.cd('~/Documents/someDirWithMatlabFunctions/')
a = testFnc(2)
```

where `testFnc.m` looks like

```
function [list2] = testFnc(list)
for i = 1:numel(list)
    list(i) = 3*list(i)
end
list2 = list;
end
```

When I run the python code, I get the following output:

```
>>> a = eng.testFnc(4)
>>> a
12L
>>> print a
12
```

My first question is what is `12L`? Furthermore, when I try to pass a list as an argument:

```
>>> a = eng.testFnc([1,2,3])
Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

It then references the line of the Matlab function in which the multiplication takes place, as where the error occurs.
I had anticipated that this might be a problem, as lists and matrices are different things. How can I properly pass variables to and from Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is 12L?**

Python supports arbitrary precision integers, meaning you're able to represent larger numbers than a normal 32- or 64-bit integer type. The `L` tells you when a literal is of this type and not a regular integer.

Note, that `L` only shows up in the interpreter output, it's just signifying the type. That's why it doesn't show up when you print it.

**How can I properly pass variables to and from Matlab?**

Straight from [MathWorks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html):

> The matlab Python package provides array classes to represent arrays of MATLAB numeric types as Python variables so that MATLAB arrays can be passed between Python and MATLAB.

[The documentation goes on to give lots of helpful examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html) for how to pass variables from MATLAB.

To pass data back to MATLAB, I recommend using numpy/scipy. [This answer explains more about how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095324/5221082)

Comment: Thanks! How can I convert the `matlab.double()` arrays to python lists?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate `matlab.double()` should return a list of lists in Python (how Python will represent the array)

Comment: For instance, [in the example shown in the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html#buglzvt), a 2-by-5 array is created and printed: `a = matlab.double([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]])`. Printing a (`print(a)`) results in a list of lists: `[[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],[6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]]`.

Comment: I see that it is still a special type (`matlab.double`), but it can be accessed the same as Python lists. To turn it into Python lists you could just call `list()` on each list within the array.

Comment: Ok, so there is no need to 'convert' it to anything, I can just manipulate elements as though in a python list.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate bingo. You can access the elements the same as you would if it were a default Python structure (list of lists), so why bother changing it? Plus not changing it probably helps with feeding it back into MATLAB.