# Convert 3D numpy Array in Python to 3D Matrix in Matlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, numpy, matrix

Is there a way to convert a 3D numpy Array in Python to a 3D Matrix in Matlab?

I only found a way to convert a 2D matrix by saving it as a dictionary using `savemat` function in `scipy.io`. But nothing clear about how to covert a 3D numpy Array in Python to a 3D Matrix in Matlab

Comment: Does this not work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997254/converting-numpy-arrays-to-matlab-and-vice-versa

You could just reshape the 3D matrix to 2D and then back

Comment: You can save it directly as 3D, nothing special is required.

Comment: @anandsun yes that works. There is no dimension limit in any of the languages

Comment: @bnaecker can you clarify how to do that? Dictionary only takes two dimensions (X as the keys and Y as values)

Comment: @IoT there is no difference between 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D or ND.

Comment: @IoT You misunderstand the dictionary argument. It's a dict whose keys are the *names* of the arrays as saved in the file, and whose values are the actual arrays in Python that are to be saved into the file. Those arrays can be of arbitrary dimension. They will be saved correctly and loaded correctly in Matlab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095265/matrix-from-python-to-matlab Another dupe

Comment: In the text it seems you want to convert np.array to dict and then save that. Just save the np.arrays as in the provided links.